# Can you choose not to rebuy a ship in elite dangerous?

Tags: elite-dangerous

If I have 2 (or more) ships, and one gets destroyed, do I have the option to *not* rebuy that ship, but instead merely switch to one of my other ones?

Comment: Note that you never *want* to do this. You should rebuy and then sell the ship instead. Rebuy cost is 1/20th (5%) of cost of the ship and you lose (at most) 10% of cost when selling a ship, so if you *don't* rebuy, you're losing out on credits worth 85%-95% of the ship's value. And loan is free (no interest), so this holds true even if you have to use loan to rebuy. And true if you can only do a partial rebuy (leaving some parts out).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm afraid you don't.  Your choices are re-buy the ship with all modules, re-buy the ship with slightly less components, or go to a Sidewinder.

Whatever option you pick you'll end up back at a station, typically the one you last docked at, and if you want to switch ships you'd have to  transport it to your current location or fly to it.

Source: Brutal, gut-wrenching experience.

Comment: Well it's good to see that you don't lose the whole fleet or your credits by choosing against a rebuy....

Comment: To get back to your other ship, sell the sidewinder, buy a hauler and fit with the biggest FSD you can get, and start jumping. Hopefully not too far away.